# Why can this type not be resolved?

Tags: c, struct, typedef, esp32

I have the following code in my C header file:

```
typedef struct mb32_packet_t {
  uint8_t compid;
  uint8_t servid;
  uint8_t payload[248];
  uint8_t checksum;
} __attribute__((packed)) mb32_packet_s;
```

Doing the following works:

```
struct mb32_packet_t packet;
```

When using this:

```
mb32_packet_t packet;
```

I get:

```
Type 'mb32_packet_t' could not be resolved
Unknown type name 'mb32_packet_t'; use 'struct' keyword to refer to the type
```

Isn't `typedef struct` intended for exactly this purpose, i.e. to be able to omit the struct keyword when defining variables of this type?

Comment: There is a typo  mb32_packet_t packet;. I think you mean mb32_packet_s packet;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your alias defined by `typedef` is called `mb32_packet_s`. So you need to use it as

```c
mb32_packet_s packet;
```

or

```c
struct mb32_packet_t packet;
```

You can also rename the alias to `mb32_packet_t`:

```c
typedef struct mb32_packet_t {
  uint8_t compid;
  uint8_t servid;
  uint8_t payload[248];
  uint8_t checksum;
} __attribute__((packed)) mb32_packet_t;
```

Then you can do both (original name without alias)

```c
struct mb32_packet_t packet;
```

and (with alias)

```c
mb32_packet_t packet;
```

This way, the names of both alias and the struct are identical, but technically, `struct mb32_packet_t` and `mb32_packet_t` are two different things that however refer to the same type.

Comment: Thanks explaining, I will use it as you describe! But for understanding my original `struct` definition: `mb32_packet_s` is actually an object, i.e. allocated memory, correct? And when later writing `mb32_packet_s packet;` this will not allocate new memory; i.e. `packet` is only kind of a reference to `mb32_packet_s` ?

Comment: No, only `packet` is an object, i.e. reserves memory. `mb32_packet_s` is just an alias for `struct mb32_packet_t`, i.e. both are types.

Comment: Now I guess I understand. And if I would define/initialize `mb32_packet_s={...}` at the end of the struct, `mb32_packet_s` would indeed be an object residing in memory?

Comment: You can't do that together with `typedef`. You can do `struct X { ...} instance = {...};`  which will create an instance (object) of the struct type, but won't define an alias. If you want both an instance and an alias, you do `typedef struct X {...} X; X instance = {...};` or `struct X {...}; typedef struct X X; X instance={...};` or `struct X {...} instance =  {...}; typedef struct X X;`

Comment: Now I got it :) ! Thanks for your patience!

Answer (score 1):

The declaration `typedef struct mb32_packet_t ... mb32_packet_s;` makes `mb32_packet_t` a tag that only works after the keyword `struct` and makes `mb32_packet_s` a type name that works on its own. To make `mb32_packet_t` a type name, swap them in the declaration or use `mb32_packet_t` in both places.

Comment: Thanks! So `typedef` does nothing in this case? I mean without `typedef` I can use it the same way, correct?

Comment: @salocinx: `typedef` says the identifier declared is a type name rather than an object or function. `typedef struct foo bar` makes `bar` a name for `struct foo`. `struct foo bar` makes an object named `bar` of type `struct foo`.

Comment: Just to clarify; at my original `struct` definition `mb32_packet_s;` is already an object of type `mb32_packet_t`, i.e. memory allocated. Later when I do `mb32_packet_s packet;` it does allocate a new object in memory with name `packet` ? Sorry for being that persistent, I want to understand.

Comment: ... or would only be memory allocated when I initialize/define the variable `mb32_packet_s` with `={...}` at the end of the `struct` definition?

Comment: @salocinx: The declaration shown first in your question, `typedef struct mb32_packet_t { … } __attribute((packed)) mb32_packet_s;`, does not define any object and does not cause memory to be reserved. It merely defines a name for a type. If you have further questions about the effects of various declarations, you should enter a new question showing complete samples. Attempting to describe them partially in comments results in lack of clarity.

Comment: Ok I get closer to understand. But if I would have defined `mb32_packet_s={...}` at the end of the `struct` definition, it would indeed be allocated in memory instead of being a name for the type `mb32_packet_t`?

Comment: @salocinx: No. The `={…}` supplies an initial value for an object. A `typedef` does not declare an object. You would get an error message from the compiler. If you have further questions about the effects of various declarations, enter a new question showing **complete samples** — complete code that can be compiled.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your patience! I think I got my head around what I initially didn't understand. So you helped me a lot!

Answer (score 1):

In your `typedef struct...` code, the `mb32_packet_t` is a [structure tag](https://stackoverflow.com/q/44180120/10871073), not the name of the defined type, which is `mb32_packet_s`. You can use the tag in a variable declaration, but *only* if you also include the `struct` keyword.

To declare a variable of the type *without* the `struct` keyword, you need to use the type's actual name, as follows:

```c
mb32_packet_s packet; // Note the "_s" rather than "_t" and the end.
```